# Shell expansion not happening

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

Why are these two commands equivalent (or so it seems based on the results I get back)? I figured the first command wouldn't work because the `*` would be treated as the glob operator but instead it got passed into `grep` just fine and interpreted as a regex pattern.

```
git diff master | grep \\+.*TODO
git diff master | grep \\+.\*TODO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filename glob will only be expanded if there's a matching file in the current directory - otherwise (barring any `nullglob` or `failglob` shell options) it will be passed as-is. So:

```
$ echo \\+.*TODO
\+.*TODO
$ printf '+foo\n+TODO\n+bar' | grep \\+.*TODO
+TODO
```

but

```
$ touch '\+.abcTODO'
$ echo \\+.*TODO
\+.abcTODO
$ printf '+foo\n+TODO\n+bar' | grep \\+.*TODO
$ printf '+foo\n+TODO\n+bar' | grep \\+.\*TODO
+TODO
```

Comment: Oh wow I never noticed that behavior. Thanks so much for explaining!